# BuildPredicate comparing two fields

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-entities, expression, automapper

I am trying to map comparisons between two fields, where previously I had only been doing field to `Expression.Constant` comparisons.

```
  private static Expression<Func<TDomainModel, bool>> BuildPredicate<TDomainModel>(string leftPropName, string rightPropName, TypeMap map)
  {
        PropertyMap leftPropMap = map.GetPropertyMaps().FirstOrDefault(pro => pro.DestinationProperty.Name == leftPropName);
        Expression leftParam = leftPropMap.CustomExpression.Body;

        PropertyMap rightPropMap = map.GetPropertyMaps().FirstOrDefault(pro => pro.DestinationProperty.Name == rightPropName);
        Expression rightParam = rightPropMap.CustomExpression.Body;

        Expression operatorBody = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(leftParam, rightParam);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TDomainModel, bool>>(operatorBody, leftPropMap.CustomExpression.Parameters[0]);
  }
```

However I always get an exception...

`The parameter 's' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.`

Both properties are on the same entity, and even use 's' in their mappings. No idea how to fix this. I've tried putting both `CustomExpression.Parameters` values into the returned Lambda, but it complains of too many overloads then.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the right expression using the same parameter as the left expression. They're different now.

I used to do this creating a [Expression.Invoke node to the right side](https://github.com/juanplopes/simple-commons/blob/master/src/Simple/Expressions/PredicateBuilder.cs#L28), then expanding invocations with a [ExpressionVisitor](https://github.com/juanplopes/simple-commons/blob/master/src/Simple/Expressions/InvocationExpander.cs).